# Steps to use Carbonite on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, carbonite

Carbonite does not yet support Windows 7 out-of-the-box. How can I get Carbonite to work on a Windows 7 machine with the current release?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/6a4db496-c32c-4c37-bb6c-e5b356e0b4f3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of Carbonite supports Windows 7 32 and 64 bit
[Carbonite Supported OS](http://cp-carbonite.kb.net/display/4n/kb/article.aspx?aid=1143&n=1&docid=100561&tab=search)

Comment: I guess all good things come to those who wait.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to be able to get it working without a supported fix from Carbonite, or at least it's fairly unlikely. Check their forums.

If you want to restore the files, you could restore them to a virtual machine running XP, and then copy them to your Windows 7 box.

Otherwise, you should think about upgrading to [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) instead, especially if you aren't backing up a ton of files. DropBox works perfectly on Windows 7.

Comment: While DropBox works on Windows 7, it is not the same as running Carbonite. With DropBox you have a finite amount of space to work with, but with Carbonite you are not limited to X GB of space.

Comment: I use DropBox and Carbonite, and will probably move to DropBox when my Carbonite subscription expires, but it's certainly not a clear-cut "upgrade". They're really two different targets, but with some overlap. If you don't need synchronization or web access, Carbonite is a much better solution. If you like synchronization (or web access) and don't mind the space limit, DropBox is obviously better..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try running the app in Compatibility Mode. Would that fix the problem?

Comment: It's the Explorer integration that's broken, so I don't think compatibility mode fixes the issue for choosing files to restore.

Answer (score 0):

Backing up files seems to work just fine on Windows 7, it's just restoring that's an issue. It [seems](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/6a4db496-c32c-4c37-bb6c-e5b356e0b4f3) that the current best solution is to use [XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) (if you've got virtualization support and Win7 Pro) to restore the files to, and then move them to Win7.

Answer (score 0):

There are also issues for Carbonite with CPU usage-- actually, Windows 7 has a CPU usage issue as well...  with Carbonite (and a few other online apps) the CPU rate sugest to 80-90% with many times being pegged flat out at 100%...  as soon as Carbonite (and the ohter apps) are placed on hold, the CPU usage dives to 10-15%...

For now I will manually manage the CPU usage but if there are no improvements (Microsoft, Carbonite and others) during the next 6 months there is going to be a needs assessment made with what other software and applications are available...  I don't care who makes it I just care I can get good results and remain connected with the rest of the internet and cyber world...